# Исключить пустые ячейки при создании xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server

Мне надо вывести структуру компании на `xml`. 
Но мне надо, чтобы пустые строки не отображались в `xml`. 
Я попытался убрать с помощью `RTRIM`, но не получается. 
У меня в таблице `v_acs_a`, в столбце `mobile` имеются пустые строки.

Вот код функций:

```
Alter function [dbo].[Asd](@hid hierarchyid, @limit int)
    Returns xml
With RTURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
BEGIN
RETURN
(
   Case when @ limit =0 then null
   ELSE
   (SELECT 
       S.hid as "@hid",
       S.level as "@level",
       S.name as "@name",
       (Select
           R. Name  as 'name',
           RTRIM(R.mobile) as 'mobile' 
        From [dbo].[V_ACS_a] R
        Where s.hid=r.hid for xml path ('employee'), type) as 'employees',
        Case when @hid=s. Hid. GetAncestor(1) then [dbo].[Asd](s.hid, @limit - 1) end
    From [dbo].[Caompanystructure] s 
    Where @hid =s.hid.GetAncestor(1) and Active=1 
    For xml path('path'), type
    )
    End
);
End
```

Comment: Думаю надо взглянуть на получающийся у вас xml и уже из него какими нибудь строковыми функциями вырезать `<mobile></mobile>` (или как он у вас там выглядит). Может конечно можно как то подавить их параметрами 'for xml', но я с ним не знаком

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы в элемент employee не вкладывался пустой mobile, тогда замените

```
RTRIM(R.mobile) as 'mobile'
```

на

```
NULLIF(R.mobile, '') as 'mobile'
```

Пример:

```
declare @employees table (name varchar(20), mobile varchar(20))
insert into @employees values
    ('Employee 1', '(123)456-78-90'),
    ('Employee 2', '              '),
    ('Employee 3', '')

select
    e.name as name,
    nullif(e.mobile, '') as mobile
from @employees e
for xml path('employee')
```

Вывод:

```
<employee>
  <name>Employee 1</name>
  <mobile>(123)456-78-90</mobile>
</employee>
<employee>
  <name>Employee 2</name>
</employee>
<employee>
  <name>Employee 3</name>
</employee>
```